# Getting the type of an existing HyperSQL table

Tags: hsqldb

HyperSQL supports different table types (memory, cached etc.).
How can I get the type of an existing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT HSQLDB_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<TABLE NAME IN UPPERCASE>'
```

HSQL converts table names to uppercase so the table name in the query also have to be in uppercase.